# Regsub not manipulating string from URL

Tags: tcl, f5

I am getting a strange TCL error when using this `iRule`, the error is:

> <HTTP_REQUEST> - ERR_ARG (line 2)     invoked from within "HTTP::uri
> [regsub "/3dnotification" [HTTP::uri] ""] "

This is an F5 irule code.

This what I have tried:

```
   when HTTP_REQUEST 
{ 
    if { not ( [string tolower [HTTP::uri]] starts_with "/socket.io" )} then { 
        HTTP::uri [regsub "/3dnotification" [HTTP::uri] ""] 
    
    # need to strip trailing slash on URI otherwise results in 404 for resources...
        HTTP::uri [regsub "\/$" [HTTP::uri] ""]
    } elseif { [string tolower [HTTP::header Upgrade]] contains "websocket" } {
        ONECONNECT::reuse disable
        set oc_reuse_disable 1
    }
    HTTP::header replace "X-Forwarded-ContextPath" "/"
}
when SERVER_CONNECTED {
    if { [info exists oc_reuse_disable] } {
        # Optional; unnecessary if the HTTP profile is disabled (goes into passthrough mode).
        ONECONNECT::detach disable
        unset oc_reuse_disable
    }
}
```

Comment: What are `not` and `starts_with` and `contains`? They're not standard `expr` syntax.

Comment: You might want to mention what program you're using, as this appears to be for something that uses tcl as a scripting language.

Comment: What does `[HTTP::uri]` evaluate to in a typical failing case? Which parts of the URI are we dealing with here? Full URI? Just the path part?

Comment: Hi, for instance if the URL is http://www.example.com:8080/main/index.jsp?user=test&login=check, URI will be /main/index.jsp?user=test&login=check. The problem is here I guess:

    HTTP::uri [regsub "\/$" [HTTP::uri] ""]

Comment: Do you get an error with all URIs, or only certain ones?

Comment: All URIs .......

Answer (score 0):

Since the URI is either a full URI or the protocol-less part (I can't quite tell which from what you say; I'll assume either is possible), removing a leading part or trailing part is going to be a little bit tricky. What you need to do is to first split the URI into its component parts, apply the transformation to the *path* part, and then reassemble. The key to the splitting and reassembly is the [uri package in Tcllib](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/uri/uri.md).

```
package require uri

# Split the URI and pick out the path from the parts
set uriParts [uri::split [HTTP::uri]]
set path [dict get $uriParts path]

# Do the transforms
set path [regsub "/3dnotification" $path ""]
set path [string trimright $path "/"];  # A different way to remove trailing slashes

# Reassemble and write back
dict set uriParts path $path
HTTP::uri [uri::join {*}$uriParts]
```

I'm assuming that you'd put the `package require` (or whatever else you need in order to get the code present) at the top of the script, and the rest inside the right `when` clause(s).

---

So that you can see what URI splitting actually does, here's your example URI split (in an interactive `tclsh` session):

```
% set uri "http://www.example.com:8080/main/index.jsp?user=test&login=check"
http://www.example.com:8080/main/index.jsp?user=test&login=check
% uri::split $uri
fragment {} port 8080 path main/index.jsp scheme http host www.example.com query user=test&login=check pbare 0 pwd {} user {}
```

As you can see, the `path` part is just `main/index.jsp` which is enormously easier to work with than the whole URI.